# Kant's distinction of freedom as transcendental idea and as practical concept: What is the benefit?

Tags: kant, free-will, causation

Prompted by the current discussion about Kant’s concept of causality of freedom [Can Free Will Exist In A Causal Material World?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/28746/can-free-will-exist-in-a-causal-material-world) I would like to understand the scope and the difference of the two Kantian concepts

- Freedom as a *transcendental* idea
- Freedom in its *practical* sense.

See Critique of Pure Reason (CPR), B561ff. Currently, I understand these two concepts as follows:

An idea is a *transcendental* idea if it refers to our way to create experience – but not to experience itself. In particular, a transcendental idea lives on the meta-level, it belongs to epistemology.

A concept is *practical* if it has a normative component, i.e. when the concept considers what should be done. In particular, a practical concepts belongs to ethics.

If you can confirm my understanding of these two concepts, I would like to know – according to Kant

- Why do we need freedom as a transcendental idea?
- Why does freedom in its practical sense explain our experience?

**Note**. I would wellcome a direct answer, not an invitation to a tour de force through the secondary literature :-)

Comment: That is actually what my BA-Thesis is about and therefore I would be glad to answer, but it takes a lot of time since I lack english sources. It would help to have an english counterpart of http://www.korpora.org/kant/verzeichnisse-gesamt.html as a textual grounding for citations, at least for CPR.

Comment: How many pages does your thesis comprise? If it's less than 100 pages I would like to read it :-). Citations should not be the problem because both of us read Kant in German editions - and concerning CPR I hope the citation is with A- and B-pages, not referring to page numbers of Akademieausgabe.

Comment: I'm working on an extraction of this very part, it's 19 pages (or the like). but I would like to answer the question here, too ;)

Comment: This is a solid question. When I look at your sentence "A concept is *practical* ...", I'm not sure about the use of the word "normative" there. I'm also not so sure about the use of "ethics" as the proper domain for Kant's moral philosophy. (*Sittlichen* hardly seems the right word, right?)

Comment: In terms of answering, I think the answer to your second question changes depending on the text in question, do you want it to cover from *Grundlegung* all the way to *Religion* or something in between?

Comment: What are your objections against the term *ethics* as naming the domain of Kant's considerations of moral philosophy? Do you mean *Sittlichkeit* instead of *Sittlichen*, because the latter does not exist as a German word? - Concerning my second question I would be happy to understand just the passage from CPR referring to the third antinomy.

Comment: @philip klocking: I'm no expert, but I've found the Cambridge edition to *Kants CPR*, edited by Guyer/Wood have done a very decent job in translation.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: It definitely is the currently best, but it is not available online afaik and not easy to obtain but by buying it overhere ;)

Comment: Up-voted the question. But I am a little confused by wording. When you say, "Why do we need freedom as...." do you mean "why" for Kant's argument? To save "freedom" is his whole purpose, of course. And I am a little stuck on "experience itself" as apart from the "experience" we create transcendentally. Maybe it's okay, just me. Anyway, got me reading third antinomy.

Comment: My first question asks for the benefit of introducing freedom as a transcendental idea. It is a theoretical term from Kant's epistemology. Why does Kant introduce this term, which problem in the context of his epistemology does he solve by introducing this term? - The second question asks for arguments from practical philosophy to support Kant's claim that causality of freedom exists. - Please let me know when my questions seem unclear also in further respects.

Comment: @jo wehler: my guess would be that he establishes freedom by a transcendental argument, and therefore he calls freedom a transcendental idea - but it's not a part of the critique I've looked at ...

Comment: @jo Wähler, A bit odd. Your question is inspiring interest, and it looks very concisely worded. Yet no answers. I feel I should grasp it (not that I could answer it), but I am still not sure exactly where the emphasis lies. In the continuity of an idea of "freedom" over "transcendental" and "practical"? I don't think you should necessarily rephrase your question. But it may have bogged down in the bottomless depths of Kantian "expertise." I, for one, have never even had the illusion of a stable understanding of "transcendental" in Kant's seemingly essential yet shifting uses of the term.

Comment: For  the term *transcendental* Kant gives a precise definiion *I call all cognition transcendental that is occupied not so much with objects but rather with our mode of cognition of objects insofar as this is to be possible a priori.* (CPR B25)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I see your answer I have a better idea of your question, and would like to attempt a slightly different interpretation.

I do not have the right editions to cite, but am basically looking at Preface to CPR,2E (very helpful), Third Antinomy, and Canon of Pure Reason, Sec. I.

I take it that Kant's main concern is not only Hume's skepticism, but the broader issue of his day: How can a natural causal determinism (the basis of scientific knowledge) be reconciled with freedom (the prerequisite of Protestant morality duty or "practical reason")? He is most concerned with preserving "practical reason" against skepticism, utilitarianism, determinism, atheism, and dogmatic authority. Even if sure knowledge loses out.

First, as to the second part of your question. I think he takes our freedom "in experience" as unproblematic.We can simply observe ourselves as "entities" among phenomena and see that we choose this or that. Moreover, to engage in science and discover "causalities" (efficient or otherwise) also requires speculative freedom. We can insert "spontaneity" into the causal chains to do "experiments." Notably he calls this not some "absolute freedom," but a type of "second causality" to preserve, I believe, its moral imperatives. So our "freedom" is traceable as an uncaused, spontaneous "cause" among sensible things, but not determined by them. Hence moral duties.

Now the difficulty. This tells us nothing about the origins, limits, or demands of this practical, experiential freedom. It is free of efficient "causality" and must therefore originate in the noumenal or transcendental realm. Here it can enjoy "logical relations" apart from temporally "causal relations." Like everything else the will or "soul" has a double existence as phenomenal and as "ding an sich." The problem is, how does Kant know? We presumably have no access to such noumenal entities.

In the Preface, 2E Kant argues that we cannot "know" we have this freedom. We cannot "know" things-in-themselves, such as our soul. But we can still "think" them hypothetically, as long as they are not self-contradicting.  So we can deduce this freedom from (1) the observation of experience, (2) the fact that it is not rationally contradicted, and (3) the necessity of some transcendental origin of moral freedom. Such knowledge enables Kant to do what he really wants to do. Which is to makes rational claims about this freedom and practical reason, preserving us from epistemological and moral anarchy.

My understanding is that Kant rewrote this material several times and that nobody, himself included, is entirely satisfied with it. To have his "two causalities" he must separate the phenomenal and noumenal, but must then tell us how he can make claims about the "noumenal" origins of "practical" reason. While I agree with the substance of your criticisms, I am not sure they affect Kant's overall argument. Science can always gain more and more knowledge of cosmological or neural "causes" in the sensible realm. But we can never secure any "final" causes except with regard to moral-practical reasoning.

Comment: I agree mostly, except on "freedom in experience". Kant is pretty straightforward that it is incoherent, a particular case of transcendental illusion, which pure reason can not help but generate by applying categories of experience beyond any possible experience. This is a direct result of his belief in unbroken causality for appearances. Then he notes that abolishing "spontaneity" would eliminate freedom altogether, unless an alternative is found. It is described as "reflection" of noumenal self in empirical character as a whole. But we can not secure final causes even in practical reasoning.

Comment: Thanks, chewing on that. Late here. Question has moved over a bit to one asked by Klocking. Since I am actually reading CPR now, citations would also help. Use of term "reflection" is intriguing.

Comment: @Nelson Alexander I appreciate your answer. Nevertheless, I am not convinced that my criticism does not affect Kant's overall argument. I think you are right when recalling Kant's arguments 1 - 3. But are they striking? Ad 1: Our experience covers only the conscious part, not the unconscious where it's happening. Ad 2: Just pointing out that an explanation is possible does not increase the explanatory power. Ad 3: Sure, Kant's needs a transcendental origin for his concept of morality. But herefrom one cannot conclude that such an origin exists. One does not need to follow Kant's theory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments on this site to my question and because of continued reading of Kant’s Critique of Pure Reaons (CPR) I would like to give an answer to my own question.

> Why do we need freedom as a transcendental idea – according to Kant?

Kant accepts the thesis of the third antinomy. It states:

*Causality according to the law of nature is not the only causality from which all the appearances of the world can be derived. In order to account for theses appearances, it is necessary also to admit another causality, that of freedom.* (CPR, B472)

In the proof of this thesis Kant argues: The law of causality which governs experience establishes an infinite chain of causes. But without a first cause each cause of this chain is up in the air and the whole chain does not constitute anything. As a consequence, one has to assume as hypothesis a first cause. It starts the whole chain of causes. The way this first cause acts, is named *transcendental freedom* (B474).

My short answer: Kant needs the hypothesis of transcencental freedom to accept the law of causality as valid for our experience.

> Why does freedom in its practical sense explain our experience – according to Kant?

Kant defines

*Freedom, in its practical sense, is the independence of our will from coercion through impulses of sensibility.* (CPR B561)

According to Kant, freedom in its practical sense is established by the fact that we can start actions on the base of rational decisions. Also “independent of the necessitation through sensible impulses” (B561) - even against them, I would add. The rational decision initiates a new chain of causality.

The basis of this argumentation is a certain view on human rationality and decision making.

Eventually, I would like to criticize both claims of Kant.

First, Kant’s scope of thinking about causality is too narrow. The only type of causation Kant considers are monocausal linear chains. He does not take into account that a certain effect may presuppose more than one cause. Neither does Kant consider the distinction between necessary and sufficient causes. About which type of causes does Kant speak? Most of all, Kant does not consider cyclic causality in the form of feed-back chains. One can discuss, whether the hypercycle of Manfred Eigen, a model of the interaction of nucleic acids (carrier of information) and amino acids (protein), exemplifies a chain of causality without a first cause.

Of course, one can apply Kant’s argument with linear chains of causality to the standard model of cosmology. Here we must admit: We do not know how the concept of causality applies when extrapolated into the far past. Using this question, one can exemplify the different methods of metaphysics and physics: The former makes the hypothesis of a first cause, the latter leaves the question open for further scientific progress.

Secondly, Kant’s scope of rational decision making is too narrow. Kant considers man primarily as a rational being. For Kant rational mental processes are conscious processes. But most processes in our brain start as unconscious process, not reachable for our introspection.

Up to now we do not have a scientific model about how a decision derives from former experiences, about their evalution and about the unconscious alignment of conflicting alternatives of action. But such models are the subject of current neuroscience, working on a determistic basis. I consider these mechanisms an
“ignoramus” but not an “ignorabimus”.

Comment: As a first input for you I will give you a short objection to your first criticism: The scope on causality is because otherwise freedom (here considered as psychological and comparative) would be "the freedom of a turnspit" (V:97): If reason was not able to become causal in nature, all responsibility for our actions would be an odd practice. I'm going on writing my work, October 28th is my deadline and I can send it to you then if you wish ;)

Comment: Concerning " If reason was not able to become causal in nature, all responsibility for our actions would be an odd practice.": Is there a certain affinity to Morgenstern "Weil, so schliesst er messerscharf / nicht sein kann, was nicht sein darf = For, he reasons pointedly / That which must not, can not be."?

Comment: One could think so and it is not far from what the critical project ends up like: In the Critique of Judgement he points out at various points that it's all about the necessary conditions of our experience *within the bounds of the constitution of our abilities of cognition (especially reason!)*. We must think so because it lies in the constition of our subjectivity and above that we cannot possibly know anything. E.g. CJ V:404 about freedom. So he has to consider our practice of blaming or he has to be a fatalist (clearly his point in V:94-99!). That has connections to rejecting solipsism.

Comment: Regarding the main question a very short answer: Practical freedom is directly defendable as knowledge, transcendental freedom is definitely **not**, but indirectly *through* practical freedom, because of its dependance on the former.

Comment: I think we agree in our text understanding of transcencental freedom. But we differ in our view whether Kant is right or wrong. Where do you see the verification of practical freedom? - My argument above is, that we do not know how decisions result from our unconscious processes, and that we do not know any mechanism for the kind of mental causation advocated by Kant. Hence I would not give up prematurely the principle of natural causality, a cornerstone of scientific explanation above the level of quantum phenomena.

Comment: I don't think Kant is arguing against natural causation in the scientific sense - he's taking that for granted.

Comment: In your original question you asked "What is the benefit?" One answer: preservation of bourgeois society. Kant seeks to secure "freedom"
for scientific inquiry and the liberal state from dogma. At the same time, he wants to secure practical reason and moral imperatives from the Jacobins, utilitarians, Humeans, relativists, et al. To do so requires his "two causalities" system, which in turn requires the noumenal-phenomenal duality. We might call this the "Goldilocks"  theory of freedom. Not too little, not too much...

Comment: @Philipp Klöcking Do you understand how practical freedom is founded on the idea of transcendental freedom, according to CPR B561? How does it work? - As a consequence transcendental freedom is a necessary condition for practical freedom. If the latter exists, then the former idea is right. That's the second part of your "very short answer" if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah Kant suspends natural causality in favour of practical freedom in case of our rational decisions for voluntary actions.

Comment: @JoWehler: Yes, I understand it, or so I hope ;) Practical freedom is the freedom of caprice having the faculty of determinition by reason (B562+B830). This faculty presupposes an "ought", which includes at least the possibility of a cause beside natural determination (B562+B575-6). This is where transcendental reason comes into play. No "ought" besides nature means total determination, that is why practical freedom is proven by imperatives (B831). This changes to categorical imperatives for pure reason (B831-834), eliminating the thinkable nature left in imperatives (B831). Then comes GMM;)

Comment: @jo wehler: there's a distinction between a voluntarist (ie in terms of will and intentionality) reading of cause and not; and I take it that Kant is interested is looking at one side of that question; I also take that in a Newtonian reading of cause in matter - will isn't operable ie isn't voluntarist.